# How to i add search button in navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have added the AppBar search icon thanks to the article below.
Article: [How to implement a Flutter Search App Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908968/how-to-implement-a-flutter-search-app-bar)

Likewise, how do I add a showSearch () to a button in the bottom navigation bar? Thanks for all.

showSearch():

```
showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch(listWords));
```

**Search Page Class**

```
class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

**PageList for NavigationBar:**

```
  List<Widget> _pageOptions = [
    AppBody(
      key: PageStorageKey('AllCryptoList'),
    ),
    FavoritesList(
      key: PageStorageKey('FavoriteCryptoList'),
    ),
    SearchPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('SearchPage'),
    ),
    InfoPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('AppInfoPage'),
    ),
  ];
```

[Output Navigation Bar ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQZxE.png)

Comment: If everyone begins to ask similar questions here, then there will be a trillion of similar, nobody interesting questions.